Error: Invalid character in header content ["Authorization"]
enter image description here
I'm having trouble collecting the token from the header. I've already checked if the token complies with JWT, and I've done the validations in my code. Honestly, I don't know what could be causing this error. My route to verify user authentication and return the token is correct, but the route to retrieve the token from the header is giving an error.
function:
static async checkUser(req, res) {

        let currentUser

        console.log(req.headers.authorization)

        if(req.headers.authorization) {

            const token = getToken(req)
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'nossosecret')

            currentUser = await User.findById(decoded.id)

            currentUser.password = undefined

        } else {
            currentUser = null
        }


        res.status(200).send(currentUser)
    }

helper:
const getToken = (req) => {

    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization
    const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1]

    return token

}

module.exports = getToken


Can you share the request you're sending and a full stacktrace of the error?
